# How to call multiple functions on the same onClick event ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have this function and when I click on the `<li>` tag, I want to call two functions, `onClick={handleProjectSelection(project)}` a handler function that comes from props from the parent component, and also this function `onClick={() => this.setState({ showingProjectSelector: false })}`

```
  renderDropdown () {
    const { displayDropdown, projects, handleProjectSelection } = this.props
    if (this.state.showingProjectSelector && displayDropdown) {
      const projectsList = projects.map((project) => (
        <li className='u-cursor--pointer u-font-size--12px'
          key={project.get('id')}
          onClick={handleProjectSelection(project)} >
          <i className='fa fa-square u-font-size--10px' style={{color: project.get('color')}}></i>
          {project.get('name')}
        </li>
      ))
```

How can I call this two functions?
This is the handler function from the parent component

```
  handleProjectSelection = (project) => () => {
    this.setState({
      projectToAdd: project.get('id'),
      projectToAddColor: project.get('color'),
      projectToAddName: project.get('name') === 'default' ? 'No' : project.get('name').substring(0, 2)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
onClick={() => {
   handleProjectSelection(project);
   anotherfunctionCall();
}}
```

Or create a single function, use that as a click handler. Inside that function call other two functions, Like this:

```
onClick={this.handleClick}

handleClick(){
   function1();
   function2();
}
```

---

See there are two ways of using arrow function:

1- Concise Body: `() => /*single expression*/`

2- Block Body: `() => {}`

In block body inside `{}` (body of the function), we can perform any number of task.

Like this:

```
onClick={() => {
   fun1();
   fun2();
   fun3();
   fun4();
   ....
   funN();
}}
```

Comment: I did what you said in the first example and it worked! onClick={() => {
            handleProjectSelection(project);
            this.setState({ showingProjectSelector: !this.state.showingProjectSelector })
          }}       But I tried to get it out in a different function like this:   handleClick (project) {
    const { handleProjectSelection } = this.props
    handleProjectSelection(project)
    this.setState({ showingProjectSelector: !this.state.showingProjectSelector })
  } but It didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: because you forgot to bind the `handleClick` method, put this line in the constructor: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`, otherwise `this` keyword will not point to class instance :)

Comment: Let's say this onClick is in a child component could I pass a prop as one of those five functions instead?

Comment: didn't get you properly, can you please explain more or show your code?

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai in that case define the onClick as async function and use await for the first function (function1). or you can also use promise

Comment: @MayankShukla can u give a refernce to some code or write down a demo ?

Comment: @MayankShukla here is my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328635/executing-a-funcrtion-after-the-action-finished-its-working

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways: 
1.

```
onClick={()=>{
    callFunctionOne();
    callFunctionTwo();
}}
```

2.

```
callTwoFunctions(){
    callFunctionOne();
    callFunctionTwo();
}

onClick={this.callTwoFunctions}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Wrap your two+ function calls in another function/method. For example

```
var Test = React.createClass({
   onClick: function(event){
      func1();
      func2();
   },
   render: function(){
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
});
```

Comment: what if first one is asynchronous ..i want the second one to be executed only after the first one gets successfully completed

Comment: you can use async-await