# Executing a function after the action finished its working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hey guys started out Redux today so was building a very basic Project of Incrementing/Decrementing the number on clicking the Increment/Decrement button.
Here is a small code for it !Please have a look

Actions-creater file

```
export const increment=(num)=>{
    return {
        type:'increment',
        payload:num
    }
}
```

reducers file

```
const change=(change=0,action)=>{
    if(action.type==='increment'){
        return action.payload+1
    }
    return change
}
export default combineReducers({
    change
})
```

Increment.js

```
class Increment extends Component {
    render() {

        console.log(this.props.ans)
        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick={()=>{this.props.increment(this.props.ans)}}>Increment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapstatetoprops=(state)=>{
    return {ans:state.change}
}
export default connect(mapstatetoprops,{increment}) (Increment)
```

Now the issue I am facing is that in Increment.js on clicking the button Increment two functions get executed

First one

```
this.props.increment(this.props.ans)
//which calls the action creater and changes the state
```

Second one

```
this.props.in(this.props.ans)
//which is a callback to the parent component as i want to pass the value to app.js from both Increment/Decrement.js and then render it to screen
```

So my App.js looks like

```
const App=(props)=>{
console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
     <Increment />
     <Decrement/>
   Count: {props.ans}
    </div>
  );
  }

const mapstatetoprops=(state)=>{
console.log(state)
return {ans:state.change}
}

export default connect(mapstatetoprops) (App);
```

Now if i `console.log(val)` in App.js and `console.log(this.props.ans)` in Increment.js file
i find that if my original value is 0 so this.props.ans in Increment.js gives me 1 but in App.js this.val still gives me 0..so before the action updates the state i am receving value in App.js. How can i make that run and update App.js after action succesfully updates the state ?

Comment: better to connect your app component with redux store and pass a single function to increment and decrement component. call that function onClick of button, also pass a string value whether to inc or dec the counter. you need counter value only in App.js

Comment: @MayankShukla modified my solution up there, can u check and let me know is that correct way ? Well its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The running flow of your action is:

- `this.props.increment(this.props.ands)` runs, at this point, `this.props.ans` is `0`
- `this.props.in(this.props.ans)` runs right after and print `0` in your `App.js`
- **The state changed and Increment Component re-rendered**
- `console.log(this.props.ands)` (in `render` function) runs.

To have the behavior as you want, you can call your `in` callback function inside the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  this.props.in(this.props.ans);
}
```